# What are Cuda shared memory capabilities

Tags: cuda

I am a newbie in cuda. According to my knowledge I must use global memory to make blocks communicate with each other, but my understanding of the stream concept and memory capabilities stuck somewhere. After searching I figured that streams queue multiple kernels in sequence and can be used to apply different kernels on different blocks.

Now I NEED to exchange arrays between 2 blocks or more. Can kernel be used to  swap or exchange data within shared memory between blocks without involving global/device memory.

Comment: What is an "arrayList", how is it "specified to block in cuda", and why is this tagged with numba *and* PyCUDA?

Comment: I running the code on numba cuda environment, I am trying to figure the idea itself either in cuda C or Python, can I transfer data between blocks.

Comment: Where would the data be stored?

Comment: I am using shared memory of each block

Comment: Shared memory has block scope. It can't be accessed from other blocks. That won't work

Comment: and if sent it to global memory, another kernel process as the global memory will send to block to transfer, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221553/discussion-between-hend-and-talonmies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I allocated block for each sub population to calculate fitness using some kernel and shared memory, can I transfer data between blocks

No. Shared memory has block scope. It is not portable between blocks. Global memory or heap memory is portable and could potentially be used to hold data to be accessed by multiple blocks.

However, the standard execution model in CUDA doesn't support grid level synchronization. Since CUDA 9, and with the newest generations of hardware, there is support for a grid level synchronization mechanism if you use [cooperative groups](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cooperative-groups/), however neither PyCUDA nor Numba expose that facility as far as I am aware.